# Default backend in haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I wonder whether there is a way to configure a default backend in haproxy, so it balances requests among a pool of backend servers (three in the example below), keeping the **default backend as a failover, only in case the three main backends are down**.

It should be something like this:

```
  server backend-0 10.10.10.0:3000 check
  server backend-1 10.10.10.1:3100 check
  server backend-2 10.10.10.2:3200 check
  server backend-default 10.10.10.3:3300 check
```

I have tried setting a `weight 0` in the backend-default, but that completely removes the server from the balancing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of - it is called "backup":

```
server backend-default 10.10.10.3:3300 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 3 backup
```

From the [haproxy docs](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.3/doc/haproxy-en.txt):

> Since version 1.1.17, it is possible to specify backup servers. These
>   servers are only sollicited when no other server is available. This
>   may only be useful to serve a maintenance page, or define one active
>   and one backup server (seldom used in TCP mode). To make a server a
>   backup one, simply add the 'backup' option on its line. These servers
>   also support cookies, so if a cookie is specified for a backup server,
>   clients assigned to this server will stick to it even when the other
>   ones come back. Conversely, if no cookie is assigned to such a server,
>   the clients will get their cookies removed (empty cookie = removal),
>   and will be balanced against other servers once they come back. Please
>   note that there is no load-balancing among backup servers by default.
>   If there are several backup servers, the second one will only be used
>   when the first one dies, and so on. To force load-balancing between
>   backup servers, specify the 'allbackups' option.